# storage of session cookies with Curl

Tags: php, curl

I would like to use a PHP script to call a website using curl and read out data there. The problem is that there is no API for this website. So far, everything works fine, but the website requires authentication and checks if a cookie has been saved. From then on, the PHP script unfortunately does not work anymore. I have no idea how to check the cookie storage, but I have to somehow manage that Curl pretends that the cookie is being stored.

Does any of you have an idea?

```
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 Gecko/13.0 Firefox/13.0";
    $header[] = "Accept: text/vnd.wap.wml,*.*";
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    if ($ch)
        {
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "");
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
        $postdata = "?username=username&password=password";
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        $tmp = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        }
    return $tmp;
```

Comment: The value for `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` should not be empty, it should point to an actual file where CURL should stores the cookies it receives from the server. `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` should point to *the same file* so that CURL uses the cookies it receives in its follow-up requests.

Comment: @rickdenhaan no need to use a filename unless you're storing cookies between different instances of a curl handle.

Answer (score 2):

cURL will keep its session cookies until you close or re-initialize the handle, so don't do that and you should be fine. In this example, any cookies you receive from `$url` will be passed on to `$new_url`.

```
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 Gecko/13.0 Firefox/13.0";
$header[] = "Accept: text/vnd.wap.wml,*.*";
$postdata = ["username"=>"username", "password"=>"password"];
$ch = curl_init($url);
if (!$ch) {
    echo "ERROR!";
    return false;
}
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $agent,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $header,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => "",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $postdata,
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
]);
$tmp = curl_exec($ch);

$curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL        => $new_url,
    CURLOPT_GET        => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => null,
    CURLOPT_POST       => false,
]);
$tmp = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $tmp;
```

A couple of notes: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is safer passed an array. This way PHP takes care of URL encoding everything for you. `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` set to an empty string will store cookies in memory, there's no need to specify `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`. Personal preference, but I find [`curl_setopt_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php) much easier to use and read.